# How to integrate On-Premweb application with Web app hosted on Azure (AAD authentication)?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory

What could be the ways to integrate a web application ( on-prem) to another web application (Azure) using azure AD authentication( happening in the background), with out the user being prompted for credentials.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your on-premise application authenticated. Based on the description, you want to implement the single sign-on for the on-premise application with the application which protected by Azure AD.

In this scenario, you can deploy ADFS on-premise and make the on-premise web application authenticate by the ADFS. Then we need to enable the trust from the ADFS to Azure AD. After build the federated trust, when the users try to access the web application which protect by Azure AD will redirect to the ADFS, and if the users already authenticate the on-premise application they will not required to enter their credential again. Here is a figure to demonstrate this progress and you can refer more detail about it from [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn441213.aspx).

[image]

And now, we can use Azure AD connect to integrate your on-premises directories with Azure Active Directory easily. You can refer the [video](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-aadconnect#configure-federation-features) on this link about different settings for this tool.